# HDD password on Dell Precision

Tags: hard-drive, security, bios, dell-precision, ata

Does anyone know exactly how Dell Precision handles HDD passwords?

The BIOS allows to set a password for any internal drive, plus an eSata drive. However, during boot, it asks for password for HDD-0 only (primary HDD). I assigned different passwords for primary and secondary drives, but it unlocks the secondary drive without asking a password. I assume then, it stores the password for the secondary drive in BIOS. Wouldn't that make it insecure?

Also, ATA specification provides for two passwords: Master and User. Since Dell BIOS allows to set only one password per HDD, I assume it is a User password. What about Master password? Setting only User password would be useless, since Master password can bypass User password. Does the BIOS Admin password perhaps double as a Master password for all HDDs in the system? The BIOS, User Manual and Dell website in general are moot on this issue.

I want to use HDD passwords to secure data on Intel 540-series SSD on Dell Precision M6800, I don't want to use TPM.

I am also interested in finding a Windows-based program for issuing ATA security commands against external (USB-connected) hard drives. The only thing I have found on the Net so far is a hdparm utility for Linux.

Thank you!